# File is not under 'rootDir' while everything should be correct

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs

I'm trying to figure out why one package of my nx monorepo is resulting in the error "TS6059". All other packages seem to work just fine (and have been in previous builds).

I've checked my index.ts files and all in/exports seem to be configured correctly. But I must have overlooked something.

The problem is with the compile module, but I can't seem to find what's going wrong. The module itself builds with no issue, and in the dist folder it also seems fine.

It's when I use something from said module it gives the following error:

```
compiling TypeScript files for project "backend-assembly"...
libs/backend/assembly/src/assembly.module.ts:1:31 - error TS6059: File 'C:/data/rnd/cskiwi/badman-next/libs/backend/compile/src/index.ts' is not under 'rootDir' 'libs/backend/assembly'. 'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files.
  The file is in the program because:
    Imported via '@badman/backend-compile' from file 'C:/data/rnd/cskiwi/badman-next/libs/backend/assembly/src/assembly.module.ts'
    Imported via '@badman/backend-compile' from file 'C:/data/rnd/cskiwi/badman-next/libs/backend/assembly/src/controllers/assembly.controller.ts'

1 import { CompileModule } from '@badman/backend-compile';
                                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  libs/backend/assembly/src/controllers/assembly.controller.ts:1:32
    1 import { CompileService } from '@badman/backend-compile';
                                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    File is included via import here.
libs/backend/compile/src/compile.module.ts:5:39 - error TS6059: File 'C:/data/rnd/cskiwi/badman-next/libs/backend/compile/src/constants/index.ts' is not under 'rootDir' 'libs/backend/assembly'. 'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files.
  The file is in the program because:
    Imported via './constants' from file 'C:/data/rnd/cskiwi/badman-next/libs/backend/compile/src/compile.module.ts'
    Imported via '../constants' from file 'C:/data/rnd/cskiwi/badman-next/libs/backend/compile/src/services/compile.service.ts'
    Imported via './constants' from file 'C:/data/rnd/cskiwi/badman-next/libs/backend/compile/src/index.ts'

5 import { COMPILE_OPTIONS_TOKEN } from './constants';
                                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  libs/backend/compile/src/services/compile.service.ts:11:39
    11 import { COMPILE_OPTIONS_TOKEN } from '../constants';
                                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    File is included via import here.
  libs/backend/compile/src/index.ts:3:15
    3 export * from './constants';
                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    File is included via import here.
libs/backend/compile/src/compile.module.ts:10:8 - error TS6059: File 'C:/data/rnd/cskiwi/badman-next/libs/backend/compile/src/interfaces/index.ts' is not under 'rootDir' 'libs/backend/assembly'. 'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files.
  The file is in the program because:
    Imported via './interfaces' from file 'C:/data/rnd/cskiwi/badman-next/libs/backend/compile/src/compile.module.ts'
    Imported via '../interfaces' from file 'C:/data/rnd/cskiwi/badman-next/libs/backend/compile/src/services/compile.service.ts'
    Imported via './interfaces' from file 'C:/data/rnd/cskiwi/badman-next/libs/backend/compile/src/index.ts'

10 } from './interfaces';
          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  libs/backend/compile/src/services/compile.service.ts:17:8
    17 } from '../interfaces';
              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    File is included via import here.
  libs/backend/compile/src/index.ts:4:15
    4 export * from './interfaces';
                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    File is included via import here.
libs/backend/compile/src/compile.module.ts:11:32 - error TS6059: File 'C:/data/rnd/cskiwi/badman-next/libs/backend/compile/src/services/index.ts' is not under 'rootDir' 'libs/backend/assembly'. 'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files.
  The file is in the program because:
    Imported via './services' from file 'C:/data/rnd/cskiwi/badman-next/libs/backend/compile/src/compile.module.ts'
    Imported via './services' from file 'C:/data/rnd/cskiwi/badman-next/libs/backend/compile/src/index.ts'

11 import { CompileService } from './services';
                                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~

  libs/backend/compile/src/index.ts:5:15
    5 export * from './services';
                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    File is included via import here.
libs/backend/compile/src/constants/index.ts:2:15 - error TS6059: File 'C:/data/rnd/cskiwi/badman-next/libs/backend/compile/src/constants/compile.constants.ts' is not under 'rootDir' 'libs/backend/assembly'. 'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files.

2 export * from './compile.constants';
                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
libs/backend/compile/src/index.ts:1:15 - error TS6059: File 'C:/data/rnd/cskiwi/badman-next/libs/backend/compile/src/compile.module.ts' is not under 'rootDir' 'libs/backend/assembly'. 'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files.

1 export * from './compile.module';
                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
libs/backend/compile/src/interfaces/index.ts:2:15 - error TS6059: File 'C:/data/rnd/cskiwi/badman-next/libs/backend/compile/src/interfaces/compile.interface.ts' is not under 'rootDir' 'libs/backend/assembly'. 'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files.

2 export * from './compile.interface';
                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
libs/backend/compile/src/services/index.ts:2:15 - error TS6059: File 'C:/data/rnd/cskiwi/badman-next/libs/backend/compile/src/services/compile.service.ts' is not under 'rootDir' 'libs/backend/assembly'. 'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files.

2 export * from './compile.service';
                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I tried removing and reinstalling the modules and nx reset

The PR can be found on: https://github.com/Badminton-Apps/badman-next/pull/57

Build command: `nx build api`

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the scope of each project through the `'tags'` field in the `project.json` file. This ensures that the typescript does not complain during import, and your problem is resolved. Please pay attention to the following code.

for `backend-compile` project edit the project.json file like this:

```
{
  // ... more project configuration here
  "tags": ["scope:backend"]
}
```

You can find much more information in the [Nx documentation](https://nx.dev/core-features/enforce-module-boundaries#tags)